# Is using AND & OR statements too much a bad practice for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a posts table like this:

----- POSTS -----
- id 
- ..etc.. 
- category1 
- category2 
- category3

Any of these categories could be filtered, and I was planning to build SQL statements like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
 WHERE category1='..sth..' 
   AND category1='..sth..' 
    OR category1='..sth..' 
    OR category2='..sth..' 
    OR category3='..sth..' 
   AND category3='..sth..' 
   OR ..."
```

Is this a bad practice and will this have performance issues ?

edit: The AND and OR statements on the query I gave was only for example.

Comment: Please format your question... It is very hard to read/edit...

Comment: Just remember to use parentheses when mixing AND/OR. "(category1= 'this' OR category1='that') AND (category2 = 'this' OR category2 = 'that'). It just depends on your precedence preference

Comment: If you're mixing AND with OR in your query, you should probably use brakets to ensure that it's easily understandable and to ensure that it is actually the query you want: there's a big difference between `WHERE Likes Soccer AND ( Likes Pizza OR Likes Whiskey )`, which is looking for a person who likes Soccer and likes either Pizza or Whiskey; so it will pick Soccer-lovers who like Pizza, Soccer-lovers who like Whiskey, Soccer-lovers who like both Pizza and Whiskey and `WHERE ( Likes Soccer AND  Likes Pizza ) OR Likes Whiskey`

Comment: Is it a bad practice? No. Are there probably better ways to do it? Yes.

Comment: category1...categoryN is a hidden form of a many-to-many table with a limit. The query is not the problem, the DB design is. Is there something fundamentally different about something being category1 and not category2?

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Yes, category1 2 and 3 are totally different from eachother. First one is "what is the post" second one is "what it is about" and last one is "how is it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is well designed then no, this is not bad practice and is in fact the ideal way to select your data.
The best thing to do is to think about how your data is going to be used and design the storage to make it easy to access the data you will need most often.
There are lots of posts here about the specifics of database design.

the sql you suggest is nonsensical (use brackets) but I suspect you had intended it only as an example.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that more conditions generally means slower query execution, but this varies considerably depending on what the conditions are.

Comment: In genreal I prefer to design so that I can as much as possible avoid OR conditions as they are generally slower than AND conditions. But if you need the OR, you need it. Often using a UNION ALL query will be faster if you have performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    SELECT * FROM posts 
    WHERE category1 in ('sth','sth')
    OR    category2 in ('sth','sth')
    OR    category3 in ('sth','sth')
   .....
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, no this is not bad practice.  Having a list of categories in your POSTS table, however, is an indication that you probably need to normalize or refactor your database structure.  I suppose it's possible that the 3 categories you show in your question could have specific special meanings, but you'd want to indicate that with better column names.

You can use the following structure, which will allow you to categorize a post into as many categories as you want.

**POSTS**:

- id

**CATEGORIES**:

- id

**POST_CATEGORIES**:

- post_id
- category_id

This structure also simplifies your query to:

```
SELECT *
  FROM POSTS
  JOIN POST_CATEGORIES
    ON POSTS.id = POST_CATEGORIES.post_id
 WHERE POST_CATEGORIES.category_id = "...sth...";
```

Comment: I thought about this but I didn't like this method because manipulating posts would be expensive this way. I mean deleting the post or updating its category would be more complex and slow. I was going to do it this way if too many AND statements would cause a big performance issue. But thanks for the idea though :)